# How to check for uninitialized array reference in java?

Tags: java, arrays, reference, null, default

I'm an early beginner and I was trying to figure out how the for-each iteration and the reference variables in java work and wrote myself a little test code to play around with.

In order to use the for-each loop I need an array first, so I created an array-reference, but didn't initialize it.

But my code won't compile, because apparently the if-statement, which I wrote to check for an uninitilized array-reference, uses an uninitilized variable.

```
public class ForEach {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        // create array reference
        int[] array;

        //check if array reference has been initialized
        if (array == null) { 
            System.out.println("No array has been found.");
        }
        else {
            for (int i : array) {
                if (array[i] != 0) {
                    System.out.println(array[i]);
                 }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

I thought the default-value of an uninitilized array-reference woud be null and I could check for null in an if-statement. 
So why do I get a compiling error, telling me the variable 'array' may not have been initialized and how do you check for a null-reference otherwise ?

Hopefully someone can help me out.
Thank you very much in advance.

P.s. wether or not my for-each loop makes any sense or not isn't the problem. For now ;-)

Comment: You need to initialise the array before using it. It could be set as null or some value, but you have to initialise it.

Comment: Had you received the array as a method parameter, your code would have worked fine.

Comment: Thanks, but I thought the compiler automatically sets every uninitialized reference-variable to null. So when can I check for null ?

Comment: Well that is simply how your Java compiler works. You have to write your program the way the compiler accepts.  No offence, your question is like: why do i have to use "to" with verbs in english. There is no hard reason for it(e.g. c behaves differently). I do  think however it indeed is a feature, if the compiler enforces initialization, as it protects you from errors - but thats my personal view.

Comment: Unlike fields, local variables are not automatically initialized to default values.

Comment: Why do you want to check it at a point where it couldn't possibly have been initialised? That's what the compiler is telling you - there is no point to writing code that is guaranteed to do nothing.

Comment: You don't have to check for it. The compiler will tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attributes of a `Class` get initialised with the default values when you construct an object for it. But the local variables defined in a method need to be intialised.

If you move the array, as done below, you will notice that the error goes away as now it is a class attribute and will be initialised with `null`.

```
public class ForEach {
// create array reference
static int[] array; 
public static void main (String[] args) {


    //check if array reference has been initialized
    if (array == null) { 
        System.out.println("No array has been found.");
    }
    else {
        for (int i : array) {
            if (array[i] != 0) {
                System.out.println(array[i]);
             }
        }

    }

}
}
```

Comment: In addition to all the other comments. That cleared it up for me, thank you :-)

Answer (score 2):

Fields on a class would be automatically set to null because they might be used eventually, but since local variables would only be used locally declaring them without initializing them can be safely considered a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

there is a difference between `null` and uninitialized.

null is still a valid value. Local variables need not have any value, but as long as they have no value, you can't read them. At all. The only legal move is to give it a value.

Just replace line `int[] array;` with `int[] array = null;` and all will be well.